# Rest API call fails with status 302 (spring security, html5)

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, jqgrid

I'm having 2 projects:
1) Restful Project with jdbc spring security (username:password) => port:9091
2) HTML5 Application with a JQGrid => port:9092

I have disabled csrf token in both the projects. Now, I'm able to hit the rest service successfully from browser and using postman and by passing the credentials

But when I try to hit the service from HTML5 Application (Jqgrid), I'm see that XHR Call is ending with status 302 and I'm not getting the results back.

So, please guide me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Additional Points:
I'm able to successfully hit the rest service from postman by passing basic authentication. But from JQGrid, I'm not able to query data even after using below code in my JQGrid. It always goes to status 302. (An FYI, I'm using stateless authentication in my spring security) :

```
loadBeforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", CURRENT_AUTH_KEY);
            },
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.withCredentials = true;
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", CURRENT_AUTH_KEY);
            },
            ajaxEditOptions: {
                beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                         jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", CURRENT_AUTH_KEY);
                }
            },
            ajaxGridOptions: { Authorization: CURRENT_AUTH_KEY } ,
```